# Predicator vs. Predicate

Tags: terminology, predicate

### BACKGROUND

According to Oxford Dictionaries Online:

> **[Predicator](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/predicator)** means "(In systemic grammar) a verb phrase considered as a constituent of clause structure, along with subject, object, and adjunct."
>
> **[Predicate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/predicate?q=Predicate)** means "The part of a sentence or clause containing a verb and stating something about the subject (e.g. *went home* in *John went home*)."

In the latter example of *John went home*, it seems, the predicate is *went home* whereas the predicator is *went*, *home* being an adjunct and thus not part of the predicator as defined.

Now, I looked further in [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28grammar%29) to better understand the difference. The article recognizes two competing notions of the predicate in theories of grammar:

> (1) Predicates in traditional grammar (e.g., *went home* in *John went home*)
>
> (2) Predicates in modern theories of syntax and grammar (e.g., *went* in *John went home*)

Which, according to the article, causes confusion as to what exactly the term predicate mean, and some grammarians came up with a new term "predicator" specifically for use (2), says the article. No problem thus far.

What bothers me: The article in its explanation of (2) says, "Other function words -- e.g. auxiliary verbs, **certain prepositions**, **phrasal particles**, etc. -- are viewed as part of the predicate." (Emphasis mine.)

Now, remember this definition of the predicate, i.e., (2) above, corresponds to the new term "predicator".

I understand that auxiliary verbs are part of this definition of predicate, because an auxiliary verb can be part of a verb cluster. But can **certain prepositions** and **phrasal particles** also?

The article has these example sentences (Words belonging to "predicate" (2) are boldfaced as in the article itself; My comments in parentheses.):

> *The butter **is in** the drawer.* (preposition ***in*** being part of the predicate)
>
> *You **should give** it **up**.* (particle ***up*** being part of the predicate)
>
> *Susan **is pulling** your **leg**.* (I don't know why leg is marked as part of the predicate. Maybe a typo?)

### QUESTION

Except for the last one, which I suspect is a typo, I'd like to know whether the preposition ***in*** and the particle ***up*** belong to the predicate as presented in (2) and thus belong to the new term "predicator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wikipedia article you linked:

> This understanding sees predicates as relations or functions over arguments. The predicate serves either to assign a property to a single argument or to relate two or more arguments to each other. Sentences consist of predicates and their arguments (and adjuncts) and are thus predicate-argument structures, whereby a given predicate is seen as linking its arguments into a greater structure.[7]

For example:

- Bob laughed. → laughed (Bob) or, laughed = ƒ(Bob)
- Sam helped you. → helped (Sam, you)
- Jim gave Jill his dog. → gave (Jim, Jill, his dog)

---

Now for the answer:

Remember that anything which is not an argument, viz...

> Other function words - e.g. auxiliary verbs, certain prepositions, phrasal particles, etc. - are viewed as part of the predicate [Wikipedia]

Now,

> 1. The butter **is in** the drawer.

This one's easy: `is in(the butter, the drawer)`

---

> 2. You **should give** it **up**.

Perhaps your confusion arises from the fact that the words aren't together.

Remember, in certain phrasal verbs (including give up), a pronoun **must** split the phrase and can't follow the verb.

So, let's have:

> 2a. You **should give up** the car.

And, by predicate calculus, we have:

2. `should give up (you, it)`

2a. `should give up (you, the car)`

---

> 3. Susan **is pulling** your **leg**

Now, [pulling someone's leg](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pull+someone%27s+leg) is an idiom that means `To make a playful attempt to fool or deceive someone.` [TFD]. She isn't literally holding your leg and pulling it. So, leg can't be an argument. (It's not a typo.)

We have: `is pulling leg(Susan, your)`

However, if it were:

> 3a. Susan **is pulling** your hand

We'd have: `is pulling(Susan, your hand)`

---

I hope this makes it clear for you. `in`, `up` and `leg` were part of the predicate indeed